# python cannot get folders to save inside of one folder

Tags: python, directory

I've run into some trouble that I believe must be an easy fix.  I am currently pulling png files from one path, and saving them in a folder in another path.  This is all done correctly.  What I try to do after is to group those folders into one `Results` folder.  My current code does not throw any exceptions, the results folder is created, but the other folders are not moving into the `Results` folder.

```
def create_folder(self,folder_name):
    '''Create folders if does not exist'''
    path,fileName = os.path.split(self.snmpPaths[0])
    target = os.path.join(path, folder_name)
    if not os.path.exists(target):
        os.makedirs(target)
    return target
```

snippet from other method

```
    if flag ==1:
        for png in pngs:
            if 'MPM' in png:
                target = self.create_folder("MPM")
                folderList.add(target)
            elif 'DAT' in png:
                target = self.create_folder("DAT")
                folderList.add(target)
            elif 'HNR' in png:
                target = self.create_folder("HNR")
                folderList.add(target)
            elif 'VER' in png:
                target = self.create_folder("VER")
                folderList.add(target)
            elif 'XT2R' in png:
                target = self.create_folder("XT2R")
                folderList.add(target)
            else:
                target = self.create_folder("Other")
                folderList.add(target)
            try:
                print "png =", png
                print "target = ", target

                os.rename(png, os.path.join(target, png))
                print "png after =", png
            except BaseException:
                print "Could not rename file for target"

    for folder in folderList:
        # path,folder = os.path.split(folder)
        # folder = "./%s" %(folder)
        try:
            print "folder = ", folder
            print "results = ", results
            os.rename(folder, os.path.join(results, folder))
            print "folder after rename = ", folder
        except BaseException:
            print "Could not rename file for results"
```

Here is a sample of my `print` statements.  I can provide more if needed.  Any help will be appreciated.  I tried to copy the same format as the png files (`./FILE`) as seen in my commented code, but I would get a `BaseException`.  An explanation would be great as to why my code is not performing the way I want it to.  I'm guessing it has to do with my `folder` variable.

png = ./VER_SUBMODE.png

target =  D:\SNMP\SPINACH\VER

png after = ./VER_SUBMODE.png

png = ./VER_TX_STATUS.png

target =  D:\SNMP\SPINACH\VER

png after = ./VER_TX_STATUS.png

folder =  D:\SNMP\SPINACH\VER

results =  D:\SNMP\SPINACH\Results_2015-05-08_09-21-01

folder after rename =  D:\SNMP\SPINACH\VER

Comment: I realize the "after" prints are not necessary

Comment: So, you want `VER` to move from `D:\SNMP\SPINACH\ ` TO `D:\SNMP\SPINACH\Results_2015-05-08_09-21-01\ ` ?

Comment: Bingo!  Cannot seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
os.rename(folder, os.path.join(results, os.path.basename(folder)))
```

Your problem was in trying to join two directories that share the same path. The above works on my machine.

Comment: Thanks!  But I am curious: `os.path.basename(folder)` just returns the folder name, ie: `VER`.  When I uncomment `path,folder = os.path.split(folder)` it gives me the same name, but gives me a `BaseException`.  Do you happen to know why? does `os.path.basename` return a string?

Comment: Yes, they both return the same thing - `VER`.The `folder = "./%s" %(folder)` line yields `./VER` as I'm sure you expected. Maybe your working directory is not what you think it is?

Comment: You're right; working directory is not the same as where the folders are located.  Thanks!